# php's mysqli_multi_query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been trying to execute a multiple query, so I've searched for a better approach on how to do this and I've read this **mysqli_multi_query** in php.

I tried it on my own to see the results, but it keeps on giving me error. Here's the code:

```
$studid = $_GET['stud_id'];
$classcode = $_GET['class'];

$conn = new MySQLi($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Can not connect to database');     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students WHERE stud_id = '".$studid."'";
$sql.= "SELECT * FROM tbl_classes WHERE class_code = '".$classcode."'";

if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                $studname = $row[3].", ".$row[1];

            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        /* print divider */
        if (mysqli_more_results($conn)) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
            $studname = $row['fname'];
        }
    } while (mysqli_more_results($conn));
}else{ echo "error";}

$conn->close();
```

With the code above, it will just print error from the else statement I set. I also tried changing the second query to `$sql .= "SELECT * FROM tbl_classes WHERE class_code = '".$classcode."'";` and also tried putting semicolon after the first query to tell the SQL that I'm done with the first query since I'm putting 2 strings together, but still no luck.

Comment: you need a semi colon inside the querry

Comment: @Dagon As what I've stated aboce, I already tried it. I tried it like this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students WHERE stud_id = '".$studid."';";` But it will just keep loading forever.

Comment: frankly in 10 years i have never used MySQL multi

Comment: @Dagon How could I execute it in a different approach, then?

Comment: can u check : $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students WHERE stud_id ="."'".$studid."';"; --- if this doesn't work either, try it by using _bind param_

Comment: First : try to run multi query in your mysql command prompt if its working fine then do next step.

Comment: @prats1411 It just keeps on loading.

Comment: @Monty how to run multi query in the console?

Comment: Postgresql : select field_names from tablename limit 5;
select field_names from tablename limit 5;

Comment: Do one thing make one query instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$studid = $_GET['stud_id'];
$classcode = $_GET['class'];

$conn = new MySQLi($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Can not connect to database');     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students WHERE stud_id = '$studid';";
$sql.= "SELECT * FROM tbl_classes WHERE class_code = '$classcode'";

if ($conn->multi_query($sql)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                $studname = $row[3].", ".$row[1];

            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        /* print divider */
        if (mysqli_more_results($conn)) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
            $studname = $row['fname'];
        }
    } while (mysqli_more_results($conn));
}else{ echo "error";}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: It will just loads forever. The content won't show.

Comment: the condition is true

Comment: It works fine if I remove the semicolon in the first query. But when I put it, it loads nonstop.

Comment: check your result variable

Answer (score 0):

**Make one query instead of two :**

```
"SELECT ts.*, tc.* 
FROM tbl_students as ts, tbl_classes as tc 
WHERE ts.stud_id = '$studid' 
AND tc.class_code = '$classcode'"
```

**Note :** If you get redundant data then use group by.